# Docker-compose on Vite

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, vite

I am dockering a Vite app with Vue. When I run `yarn dev`from my system, everything is Ok, but when I launch the same command from my dockerfile, I got the following error

```
yarn run v1.22.5

warning package.json: No license field

$ vite

failed to load config from /app/vite.config.ts

error when starting dev server:

Error: spawn Unknown system error -8
```

My dockerfile is

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]
```

And my docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  client:
    build: 
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: client.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

My folder structure is

```
client
|-public
|-src
|-node_modules
|-package.json
|-vite.config.ts
|- ... rest of files
dockerfiles
|-client.dockerfile
docker-compose.yml (at root level)
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, for some reason docker used the `node_modules` folder from the project instead of its own (with `RUN npm install` command).
I've solved it by adding a `.dockerignore` file and ignoring the `node_modules` of the project.

```
//.dockerignore

node_modules/*
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't quite figured this one out yet, but I think it has something to do with the alpine node image. Try using one of the "slim" images of node instead.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to run the project in a docker container and use docker compose to run fronted as well as other containers at the same to let the project run locally. I had installed the defined version of the vite like `npm install vite@3.2.2` and then the docker needs the esbuild to be a Linux package for windows and arm64 for mac so I force installed the `esbuild-linux-64` on the root folder and then used the command `docker-compose up` to run the container and it worked.